# Where is require() searching for a index.js in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

I'm trying to understand the hierarchy of folders in a nodejs project.
I know that if you have a *index.js* in a *foo* folder on *node_modules* and you call `require('foo')`, it will return the *index.js*. Okay.

My question is: When I (for example) download the *'underscore'* package from npm, it creates a underscore folder inside the *node_modules* and it contains some js files. The *index.js* is in another folder inside the undersocre folder, called modules (there are *index.js* and *index-all.js*). *Index.js* is not suposed to be outside that *'modules'* folder?

Answer (score 0):

The entire loading logic for `require()` in nodejs is described here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together.

In the case of underscore, there is a `package.json` file that contains a `main` entry point that tells it to run `underscore.js` as the entry point to the module (when you are using `require()` to load it).